# Forms 12c Open file and release Forms control

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracleforms

How can i open file in forms 12c.

I tried with following code but does not release control back to the forms instance until we close the file. I want file to be open and controls to be remain back with forms instance.

```
webutil_host.host('cmd /c C:\temp\test.txt');
```

Please can somebody help me.

Answer (score 2):

Got it done it with following code

```
webutil_host.NonBlocking('cmd /c C:\temp\test.txt');
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can achieve the same functionality with

```
web.show_document('file:\\C:\temp\test.txt');
```